# Adding objects of a specific type to a generic Array<Any> in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, casting

How do you add an object of a specific type to a generic **Array:[Any]**? My understanding is that *Any* should be able to contain any other object. Is this correct? Unfortunately I get an error message when I add specific objects to the generic array.

Example

An array of objects of type "SpecificItemType"

```
var results:[SpecificItemType] = []
... // adding various objects to this array
```

The generic target array for these objects

```
var matchedResults:[Any] = []
matchedResults += results
```

Error Message

```
[Any] is not identical to UInt8
```

What's the problem here? The error message didn't really help.

One more note: Interestingly it is possible to add single objects using append. so the following works

```
matchedResults.append(results.first)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler cannot resolve the type constraints on

```
func +=<T, C : CollectionType where T == T>(inout lhs: ContiguousArray<T>, rhs: C)
```

because you're trying to add `[SpecificType]` to `[Any]`, hence `T != T`.

You can fix this by upcasting the most specific array.

```
var r = results.map { $0 as Any }
matchedResults += r
```

---

Concerning the puzzling error, it's due to the overloading on the `+=` operator. The compiler tries to resolve the various versions of the operator, eventually finding this one here:

```
func +=(inout lhs: UInt8, rhs: UInt8)
```

Probably it's the last one it tries to resolve, so it throws an error here, telling you that `[Any]` is different than the expected type for `lhs`, i.e. `UInt8` in this case.

Comment: Beautifully explained!

Answer (score 0):

First of all change *Any* to *AnyObject* and try following:

`matchedResults += (results as [AnyObject])`